# how to make two FFT objects for the left and right channel with the minim library for processing

Tags: java, audio, processing, minim

I have the following code that creates an FFT object from an audio file
see the code below:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;

Minim       minim;
AudioPlayer player;
FFT         fft;


void setup(){
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("audio.mp3");
  fft = new FFT( player.bufferSize(), player.sampleRate() ); 
  fft.logAverages(86, 1); 
  fft.window(FFT.HAMMING);
  numZones = fft.avgSize();
}
```

But now i want to create two FFT objects for the left and the right channel. So in the end i want to have a fftLeft = new FFT(audio.left)
and a fftRight = new FFT(audio.right)

i have tried the method `.getChannel(player.LEFT)` but this didnt work. does anyone have a tip or suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the FFT's [forward()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/fft_method_forward.html) method you can pass the channel you want.

Something like this:

```
//in setup()
fftLeft  = new FFT( player.bufferSize(), player.sampleRate() );
fftRight = new FFT( player.bufferSize(), player.sampleRate() );
//in draw()
fftLeft.forward(player.left);
fftRight.forward(player.right);
```

Here's a tweaked version of the SoundSpectrum sample that comes with minim:

```
/**
  * An FFT object is used to convert an audio signal into its frequency domain representation. This representation
  * lets you see how much of each frequency is contained in an audio signal. Sometimes you might not want to 
  * work with the entire spectrum, so it's possible to have the FFT object calculate average frequency bands by 
  * simply averaging the values of adjacent frequency bands in the full spectrum. There are two different ways 
  * these can be calculated: <b>Linearly</b>, by grouping equal numbers of adjacent frequency bands, or 
  * <b>Logarithmically</b>, by grouping frequency bands by <i>octave</i>, which is more akin to how humans hear sound.
  * <br/>
  * This sketch illustrates the difference between viewing the full spectrum, 
  * linearly spaced averaged bands, and logarithmically spaced averaged bands.
  * <p>
  * From top to bottom:
  * <ul>
  *  <li>The full spectrum.</li>
  *  <li>The spectrum grouped into 30 linearly spaced averages.</li>
  *  <li>The spectrum grouped logarithmically into 10 octaves, each split into 3 bands.</li>
  * </ul>
  *
  * Moving the mouse across the sketch will highlight a band in each spectrum and display what the center 
  * frequency of that band is. The averaged bands are drawn so that they line up with full spectrum bands they 
  * are averages of. In this way, you can clearly see how logarithmic averages differ from linear averages.
  * <p>
  * For more information about Minim and additional features, visit http://code.compartmental.net/minim/
  */

import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;  
AudioPlayer jingle;

FFT fftLogLeft,fftLogRight;

float height3;
float height23;
float spectrumScale = 4;

float centerFrequency;

PFont font;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 480);
  height3 = height/3;
  height23 = 2*height/3;

  minim = new Minim(this);
  jingle = minim.loadFile("jingle.mp3", 1024);

  // loop the file
  jingle.loop();

  // create an FFT object for calculating logarithmically spaced averages
  // left channel
  fftLogLeft = new FFT( jingle.bufferSize(), jingle.sampleRate() );
  fftLogLeft.logAverages( 22, 3 );

  fftLogRight = new FFT( jingle.bufferSize(), jingle.sampleRate() );
  fftLogRight.logAverages( 22, 3 );

  rectMode(CORNERS);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  //run FFT on left channel
  fftLogLeft.forward( jingle.left );
  //run FFT on left channel
  fftLogRight.forward( jingle.right );

  plotFFT(fftLogLeft,height-50,"Left Channel");
  plotFFT(fftLogRight,height,"Right Channel");
}

void plotFFT(FFT fft,float y,String prefix){
  // draw the logarithmic averages
  {
    // since logarithmically spaced averages are not equally spaced
    // we can't precompute the width for all averages
    for(int i = 0; i < fft.avgSize(); i++)
    {
      centerFrequency    = fft.getAverageCenterFrequency(i);
      // how wide is this average in Hz?
      float averageWidth = fft.getAverageBandWidth(i);   

      // we calculate the lowest and highest frequencies
      // contained in this average using the center frequency
      // and bandwidth of this average.
      float lowFreq  = centerFrequency - averageWidth/2;
      float highFreq = centerFrequency + averageWidth/2;

      // freqToIndex converts a frequency in Hz to a spectrum band index
      // that can be passed to getBand. in this case, we simply use the 
      // index as coordinates for the rectangle we draw to represent
      // the average.
      int xl = (int)fft.freqToIndex(lowFreq);
      int xr = (int)fft.freqToIndex(highFreq);

      // if the mouse is inside of this average's rectangle
      // print the center frequency and set the fill color to red
      if ( mouseX >= xl && mouseX < xr )
      {
        fill(255, 128);
        text(prefix + "Logarithmic Average Center Frequency: " + centerFrequency, 5, y - 25);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
      }
      else
      {
          fill(255);
      }
      // draw a rectangle for each average, multiply the value by spectrumScale so we can see it better
      rect( xl, y, xr, y - fft.getAvg(i)*spectrumScale );
    }
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

- You'll need to drop an .mp3 file onto the sketch before running. Either name it "jingle.mp3" or change the call to `loadFile()` to use the correct file name
- I left the logarithmic averages as an example. They will be more useful for visualisation than linear or no averages at all. For more useful tips on FFT for sound visualisation in Processing see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408388/how-to-filter-fft-data-for-audio-visualisation) and [Dan Ellis' Music Signal Processing course](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/e4896/index.html) taught at Columbia University (as some of the practice is using Processing's minim library)

Comment: works like a charm! i had fftLeft.forward(player.mix);