# How do I make a PGraphics filled with points (grade of white is based on the amplitude) and texture that to the ever evolving arc?

Tags: audio, processing, visualization

I'm working on an audio visualisation that's basically supposed to be a circular spectrogram. I have a graph that shows the frequency already and an arc, that evolves based on the time passed. Now I would like to fill the arc with white points based on the amplitude of each frequency, much like here: https://vimeo.com/27135957. Apparently, I need to make a PGraphics that is filled with points, which change from white to black based on the amplitude. Then I need to texture the arc with this graphic. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;
FFT fft;
PGraphics pg;
PShape arc;

float deg = 90;
float rad = radians(deg);

void setup()
{
  size(1000, 1000);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  song = minim.loadFile("Anthology.mp3");
  song.play();

  fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());

  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  fft.forward(song.mix);

  for (int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++)
  {
    pushMatrix();
    stroke(255);
    line(i, height, i, height - fft.getBand(i)*0.5);
    popMatrix();
    println(fft.getBand(i));

    //Map Amplitude to 0 → 255, fill with points and color them
    float brightness = map(fft.getBand(i), -1, 1, 0, 255);
    pg.beginDraw();
    pg.endDraw();

    fill(255, 255, 255,);
    noStroke();
    float evolution = radians(map(song.position(), 0, song.length(), 90, 450));
    //texture(pg);
    arc(height/2, height/2, height-100, height-100, rad, evolution, PIE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few concepts that appear unclear based on your code:

1. If you plan to render the arc within the `pg` PGraphics instance access pg with `.` notation and call drawing functions in between `beginDraw()`/`endDraw()` calls. At the moment there is nothing rendered in pg and pg isn't rendered anywhere using `image()`. For more details see the [createGraphics()](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html) reference, run the sample code/ tweak it/ break it/fix it/understand it
2. Similarly `PShape arc` is created but is not used
3. There is a commented attempt to use `pg` as a texture however the texture mapping is unclear

If using both `PGraphics` and `PShape` is confusing you can achieve a similar effect with `PGraphics` alone: simply render some larger gray dots instead of arcs. It won't be an identical effect but it will have a very similar look with less effort.

Here's a variant based on your code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;
FFT fft;

PGraphics pg;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600, P2D);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  song = minim.loadFile("jingle.mp3", 1024);
  song.loop();

  fft = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());
  // optional: use logarithmic averages: clover to how we perceive sound
  fft.logAverages( 30, 6 );
  // setup pg graphics layer disable fill, make points stroke thick
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.strokeWeight(3);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.endDraw();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  image(pg, 0, 0);
  // perform FFT on stereo mix
  fft.forward(song.mix);
  // center coordinates
  float cx = width * 0.5;
  float cy = height * 0.5;
  // count FFT bins
  int fftSpecSize = fft.specSize();
  // calculate the visual size for representing an FFT bin
  float sizePerSpec = (height * 0.5 ) / fftSpecSize;

  stroke(255);
  noFill();

  // start @editing@ the pg layer (once
  pg.beginDraw();

  // start the FFT graph shape
  beginShape();

  // for each FFT bin
  for (int i = 0; i < fftSpecSize; i++)
  {
    // get the vands in reverse order (low frequencies last)
    float fftBand = fft.getBand(fftSpecSize - i - 1);
    // scale FFT bin value to pixel/render size
    float xOffset = fftBand * 10;
    // map FFT bins to 0-255 brightness levels (note 35 may differ 
    float brightness = map(fftBand, 0, 35, 0, 255);

    // draw the line graph vertex
    vertex(cx + xOffset, cy + sizePerSpec * i);
    // map song position (millis played) to 360 degrees in radians (2 * PI)
    // add HALF_PI (90 degrees) because  0 degrees points to the right and drawing should start pointing down (not right)
    //float angle = map(song.position(), 0, song.length(), 0, TWO_PI) + HALF_PI;
    // as a test map it to a lower value
    float angle = (frameCount * 0.0025) + HALF_PI;
    // map radius from FFT index
    float radius = map(i, 0, fftSpecSize - 1, 0, width * 0.5);
    // use mapped brightness as point stroke 
    pg.stroke(brightness);
    // use polar coordinates mapped from the centre
    pg.pushMatrix();
    pg.translate(cx,cy);
    pg.rotate(angle);
    pg.point(radius,0);
    pg.popMatrix();
    // alternatively use polar to cartesian coordinate conversion
    // x = cos(angle) * radius
    // y = sin((angle) * radius
    // cx, cy are added to offset from center
    //pg.point(cx + (cos(angle) * radius),
    //         cy + (sin(angle) * radius));
  }
  // finish FFT graph line
  endShape();
  // fnish pg layer
  pg.endDraw();
}
```

**Note**

- you may want to change `jingle.mp3` to your audio file name
- for the sake of a test with a short track I used an arbitrary mapping of the `angle` (same as `evolution` in your code): there is a commented version that takes the track duration into account
- the grayscale point position is rendered using coordinate transformations. Be sure to go through the [2D Transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) and bare in mind the order of transformations is important. Alternatively there is a versioon that does the same using the polar (angle/radius) to cartesian (x,y) coordinate system transformation formula instead.

[image: FFT line plot verticall drawn leaving grayscale trails rotating clockwise as a radial spectrogram]

P.S. I also wondered how to get nice visuals based on FFT data and with a few filtering tricks results can be nice. I recommend also checking out [wakjah's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408388/how-to-filter-fft-data-for-audio-visualisation).